# How to get woocommerce products of current language with WP_Query?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, multilingual

I changed shop page pagination and added custom code to load products using ajax on page scroll. My site is multilingual and i am using WPML. The code is working fine in default language but in other language instead of showing products of that language its showing me products of default language i.e. english. Means i want to show translated products correspond to specific language.

Here is my code ajax code :

```
var $ = jQuery;
var flag=1;
var limit=0;
$(window).scroll(function(){
         if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
            limit++;
            if(flag==1)
            {
                $(".lazy_lode_img").css('display','block');//display loading image
                $.ajax({
                    url:"<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri();?>/ajax.php", // ajax page
                    type:'POST',
                    data:{ 'paged':limit}, // send page no
                    dataType:"html",
                    success: function(product_data){
                        //alert(product_data);
                        if(product_data!=0)
                        {
                            $( ".shop-products.row.grid-view" ).append(product_data);
                            $(".lazy_lode_img").css('display','none');
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            flag=0;
                           // $('#k_test').append('<div class="news" id="no_news" style="text-align:center;">NO MORE PRODUCT</div>');
                            $(".lazy_lode_img").remove();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

And here is my php code:

```
$page_no = $_POST['paged'];
$post_per_page=6;
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => $post_per_page,//set post per page
    'paged'           => $page_no,//set offset for limit
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'post_status'=>'publish',
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
        /*$price = get_post_meta( $query->post->ID, '_regular_price', true );
        $price=round($price,2);
        if ((int) $price == $price)
        {
            $price=$price.'.00';
        }*/
        ?>
        <div class="item-col col-xs-6 col-md-4 col-sm-4 post-6303 product type-product status-publish has-post-thumbnail product_cat-all-products product_cat-tarts instock shipping-taxable purchasable product-type-simple">
            <div class="product-wrapper product-wrapper2">
                <div class="list-col4">
                    <div class="product-image">
                        <a class="twoimg" href="<?php echo get_permalink( $query->post->ID );?>" title="Blueberry Frangipane Tart">
                            <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $query->post->ID, 'shop_catalog' );?>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="home-product-title">
                        <h2 class="product-name">
                            <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $query->post->ID );?>" style="color:black;"><?php echo $query->post->post_title;?></a>
                        </h2>
                        <span class="arrow-img"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
    endwhile;
}
else
{
    echo '0';
}
```

I don't understand where should i pass language code so that it will fetch products of current selected language on front-end.

Comment: Did you read this one,https://wpml.org/forums/topic/show-default-languageplugin-if-not-translated/

Comment: I tried by using switch_lang() but its still showing me english version products..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending time on it finally i found the solution.

I just added an argument

```
'lang' => $current_language
```

Now my query arguments looks like:

```
 $args = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => $post_per_page,//set post per page
    'paged'           => $page_no,//set offset for limit
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'post_status'=>'publish',
    'lang' => $current_language
);
```

And it works like charm.